# why doesn't dbt set its target folder in `/tmp/`?

Tags: dbt, tmp

When executing `dbt run`, `dbt test`, `dbt compile` or `dbt compile`, compiled SQL files are written to the `target-path` (by default `./target/`) relative to the current path. So if you're jumping around the directory tree and run `dbt` commands in the wrong folder, a new `target/` dir is created and populated in the current working directory.

The target folder [can be configured](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/target-path#configuration) to be just about anywhere including an absolute path somewhere.

Questions:

- Why would dbt use relative paths for the target?
- By extension, why would dbt **not** default to using something like `/tmp/dbt-target-<dbt-project>/`?
- Is it a bad idea to set `target-path` to an absolute path such as a subdir in `/tmp/`?

---

I've tried running the dbt commands with the flag `--target-path /tmp/dbt-<my-project>/` with no adverse effects so far.